# Creating a DLNA server/service in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, upnp, dlna

I would like to create a DLNA server in VB.NET.
Since a lot of multimedia devices start supporting DLNA, i would like to see what is possible. Not only streaming video/audio and pictures but see what else can be done.

### Anybody any starting points? protocol info, some basic code to get started?

DLNA is based on UPnP so i geuss that is the direction i have to start looking.

Comment: there is a c# implementation here: http://nmaier.github.io/simpleDLNA/

Answer (score 10):

[UPnP MediaServer using Intels SDK for Windows Home Server and Xbox 360](http://www.mperfect.net/whsUpnp360/) is written in C# and does not have all the functionallity required but it is a start.

I'd like to see an open source implementation of DLNA in .NET

Comment: Yeah me too. I'd like to see an open source implementation of DLNA in .NET

Answer (score 6):

You have to be a member of the DLNA community or pay $500 to be able to get a full specification of the protocol according to their [homepage](http://www.dlna.org/industry/certification/guidelines/).

Intel has a [tool](http://www.intel.com/cd/ids/developer/asmo-na/eng/downloads/upnp/tools/index.htm) for generating source code which is DLNA compliant at their hompepage. That could be a good start for just playing around and trying your ideas without having to buy the specification.

Comment: This link is dead. Can you name the "tool" please and give some more informations about it.

Answer (score 6):

This is a esy to understand 
UPnP AV Control Point VB.Net [sample](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=6104&lngWId=10)

Comment: Thanks! this is a very complete client side example.

Comment: I can't contact the author directly by mail, because no valid address is known. Does anyone know, how to send a picture to the media renderer (to show on the target device, like an album cover)?

Answer (score 3):

You can get a lot of information about the various UPNP protocols, including DLNA from the UPNP website [here](http://www.upnp.org/resources/default.asp).  This includes a zip file will all the service definitions and a list of existing SDKs from which you can start.

Comment: Thanks! Good resource and starting point.

Comment: The link leads to the main UPnP page, which has a giant 'DOWNLOAD ZIP' link on it.

Answer (score 1):

The Mono Project has a pretty good open source implementation of the UPnP protocol.
https://github.com/mono/mono-upnp