# Where can I get started writing a media server in C# like PlayOn

Tags: c#, asp.net, media, upnp, dlna

Where can I get started writing a media server in C# like PlayOn
http://www.themediamall.com/playon

UPDATE:
I have learned that PlayOn is a is a DLNA/UPnP media server but I am still looking for C# example implementation of this type of server. I am placing a bounty and will award it if you can point me to some sample code that I can use to server photos and/or video content to a media client like XBOX 360, Playstation 3, Media Center, or Media Center Extenders

Comment: If you vote to close please leave a comment as to why

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After more research I have learned that PlayOn is a is a [DLNA](http://www.dlna.org/industry/certification/guidelines/)/[UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPnP_AV_MediaServers) media server. There is not lots of information on it but there are a few. If anyone can reference an example that would be awesome.

here some links I found after discovering I was looking for [DLNA](http://www.dlna.org/industry/certification/guidelines/)/[UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPnP_AV_MediaServers)

[Creating a DLNA server/service in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274470/creating-a-dlna-server-service-in-vb-net)

[C# UPNP/DNLA Media Server Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418451/c-upnp-dnla-media-server-library)

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544152/connect-my-360-to-an-application) question may also help point you in the right direction.

Specifically the accepted answer point to the [Platinum UPnP library](http://www.plutinosoft.com/blog/projects/platinum). Whilst it's a C++ library, it looks promising and i'm sure it could be integrated with a C# solution or at least give you ideas for your own implementation.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be not to write you own server for the reason that [Windows Media Services](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/9series/server.aspx) - which is a great FREE streaming server from Microsoft is available already. It focuses on the heavy lifting of how do you stream, formats etc... is well documented and understood which makes deployment easier. Your focus could then be on the areas it sucks at, which is client front end - i.e. a nice web or [Silverlight](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2008/01/09/silverlight_media_application_service/) interface, maybe an RSS feed of videos. This shouldn't be hard as the server API and how to write code against it [is well documented](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/windowsmedia/).

Answer (score 1):

[XNA Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/xna/default.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps have a look at the codebase for [Media Portal](http://www.team-mediaportal.com/)

Here is the developer page 
http://www.team-mediaportal.com/contribute_to_mediaportal.html

There is also a media sharing library on code plex that might help

http://www.codeplex.com/blueportal

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of things to look into:

/whsUpnp360
UPnP MediaServer using Intels SDK for Windows Home Server and Xbox 360 (written in C#)

http://www.mperfect.net/whsUpnp360/

UPnP library for C#?
http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/741142-upnp-library-c