# Connect my 360 to an application

Tags: c#, xbox360

Is there a way (using .net) to connect an application i write to the 360?  What I want to do is write a custom media sharing application, and have the contents stream to an xbox.

I see that there is an application for the mac called [Connect360](http://www.nullriver.com/products/connect360) that does this, so there must be a way, right?

Comment: A System/360?  First, you're going to need a Token Ring card and some BNC cable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XBMC](http://xbmc.org) which uses the [Platinum UPnP library](http://www.plutinosoft.com/blog/projects/platinum), had Xbox 360 support [at one point](http://www.plutinosoft.com/blog/category/blah-blah/213). Not sure if it still does. However, both are open source and under revision control, so the source code should give you a good idea of how to implement UPnP support in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Write a [DLNA server](http://www.allegrosoft.com/downloads/UPnP_DLNA_White_Paper.pdf). There's a media sharing server for linux that you can look into for an idea on how the protocols work, but I don't remember what it's called.

Comment: AFAIK, the 360 is NOT DLNA certified. It supports UPnP however requires the UPnP renderer to be very specific in how it exposes the media.

Comment: My specific experience is with the PS3, so DLNA might not be the way to go. I assumed the 360 was a DLNA device because TVersity supports the 360, but TVersity may be emulating WMP as stated by Jarin Udom.

Comment: Yes, the PS3 is DLNA compliant, the 360 on the other hand required specific "quirks" to be implemented in the renderer AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Connect360 emulates Windows Media Server. All the 360 is doing is connecting to a Windows Media Server like it would normally (or so it thinks).

Answer (score 0):

I think in XNA there is a object that can be used for sockets.  You'll probably need to utilize the socket object to connect back to your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use the media player built into the Xbox 360, i think you will need to look into media streaming standards and what one's the 360 recognizes (i'm not sure myself).

You may also be interested in [TVersity](http://tversity.com/) which handles a wide range of streaming capabilities.