# Stream media with Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, streaming, windows-media-player

In windows 7 there is option to stream media over the network group.
e.g stream video from my computer to my TV over the lan network.

To do this I need to use the Windows Media Player, add the files to the playlist and select the target device.

I want to do it automaticly in my program, I want to select file and stream it like the Windows Media Player dose.

Is it known protocol? (My TV for example supported this kind of streaming, so I believe that is known protocol)
Any idea for how can I doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The protocol is called DLNA. There seem to be plenty of libraries out there that should handle it, I actually found this post while searching how to make a DLNA client application, and I'm planning on using OhNet by OpenHome, as per a recommendation in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274470/creating-a-dlna-server-service-in-vb-net).